# Как использовать Make?

Tags: c++, makefile, gnumake

Для следующей программы необходимо добавить автоматизацию сборки многофайлового проекта с использованием сценарных оболочек и автосборщиков.

Как использовать Make?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main() 
{
    int N, j_max;
    cout << "\n Input size of matrix: "; cin >> N;   cout << endl;
    srand(time(NULL));

    int **m = new int* [N];
    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) 
    {
        m[i] = new int[N];
    }

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) 
    {
        for (int j=0; j<N; j++)  
        {
            m[i][j] = rand()%50-0; 
            cout << " " << m[i][j] << "\t";  
        }
        cout << endl; 
    }
    cout << endl;

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++)
    {
        j_max = 0;
        for (int j=1; j<N; j++)
            if (m[i][j_max] < m[i][j]) 
            {
                j_max = j;
            }
        m[i][j_max] = 0;
    }

    for (int i=0; i<N; i++) {
        for (int j=0; j<N; j++)  {
            cout << " " << m[i][j] << "\t";  }
        cout << endl;  }
    cout << endl;

    bool kl = true;
    for (int i=1; i<N; i++)
    {
        for (int j=0; j<i; j++)
        {
            if (m[i][j] != m[j][i])
                kl = false;
        }
    }
    if (kl)
    {
        cout << " Symetric matrix." << endl;
    }
    else
    {
        cout << " Not symetric matrix." << endl;
    }

    cout << endl;

    delete [] m;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: Где же тут "многофайлового"? В данном случае, IMHO, make не нужен.

Comment: По-моему, Вам немного не хватает базовых знаний. Посмотрите краткое описание сборки программы: http://b3d.int.ru/node/11

Answer (score 2, accepted):

например, так:

если файл называется, к примеру, prog.cpp, то его компиляцию можно запустить командой:

```
$ make prog
```

благодаря *неявным правилам* ([implicit rules](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Implicit-Rules.html)), которые можно просмотреть, передав программе *make* опцию `-p`, фактически будет интерпретирован мини-makefile такого содержимого:

```
%: %.cpp
  $(LINK.cpp) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

что, после подстановки всех имеющихся переменных (которые можно увидеть в выводе всё той же команды `make -p`), превратится в команду:

```
g++ $(CXXFLAGS) $(CPPFLAGS) $(LDFLAGS) $(TARGET_ARCH) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@
```

где `$^` — это строка `prog.cpp`, а `$@` — это строка `prog`.

остальные же переменные (`CXXFLAGS`, `CPPFLAGS` и т.д.) по умолчанию не определены, и их значения (`$(CXXFLAGS)`, `$(CPPFLAGS)` и т.д.) будут подставлены как пробелы.

---

учитывая вышесказанное, начальным этапом, стартовой точкой может быть *makefile* такого содержимого:

```
all: prog
```

интерпретировать его можно, просто вызвав программу *make* без аргументов:

```
$ make
```

в названии цели (`all`) нет ничего «сакрального», просто так исторически сложилось, что самую первую цель (то есть, выполняющуюся по умолчанию) называют (довольно часто) именно так.

Comment: Можно добавить, что если есть environment-переменные LDFLAGS, LDLIBS и пр. то будут подставляться их значения, если эти переменные не переопределены в makefile (однако, эти значения в свою очередь м.б. переопределены аргументами вызова make)

Comment: @avp, у вас, кстати, нет, чисто случайно, под рукой *ms/windows*? меня давно терзают смутные подозрения, что там упомянутое в ответе правило должно звучать не как `%: %.cpp`, а как `%.exe: %.cpp`, но проверить совершенно негде.

Comment: Только добрался до компа. Сейчас винды нет, а ближе к полуночи дома посмотрю, тогда и отпишусь.

Comment: Нет, make -p в MinGW (GNU Make version 3.78.1) пишет точно такое же правило `%: %.cpp
#  commands to execute (built-in):
 $(LINK.cpp) $^ $(LOADLIBES) $(LDLIBS) -o $@` Поэтому make толком не работает. Файл-то на диске `prog.exe`, а в makefile `all: prog`, а default для `all: prog.exe` нет. Кстати, CXX=/mingw/bin/g++ пришлось ручками добавлять, почему-то без полных путей CreateProcess не срабатывает, но с этими виндузовыми штучками я уже разбираться не стал. / Если еще какие-то вопросы есть, не стесняйтесь (можно в чате C/C++)

Comment: @avp, спасибо! а запустить `prog` (без суффикса) в *ms/windows* ведь нельзя? тогда, выходит все подобные *implicit rules* надо править. только багрепорт, видимо, надо не на gnu.org слать, а на mingw.org. ведь make у вас, я так понимаю, является частью mingw.

Comment: Из `cmd` (и из `system()` в программе) и без .exe запускается. А вот make.exe у меня в UnixUtils (я не точно помню, почему так. Смутно вспоминается, что когда я нашел MinGW (лет 5-6 назад) там make не было. И я сгоряча почти написал свой простенький, а потом как-то случайно наткнулся на UnixUtils и свой забросил. Ну, в винде я же не работаю, иногда развлекаюсь, что-то пробуя для ХК (теперь SO))

Answer (score 1):

Пример небольшого makefile позволяет собирать небольшие проекты

```
EXEC=glib_test
SOURCE=$(wildcard *.c)
OBJS=$(SOURCE:.c=.o)
DEPEND=$(SOURCE:.c=.d)
CXX=gcc
CFLAGS=-g2 -Wall `pkg-config --cflags glib-2.0`
LDFLAGS=-g2
LIB=-lglib-2.0

$(EXEC):$(OBJS)
    $(CXX) $(LDFLAGS) -o $@ $^ $(LIB)

%.o:%.c
    $(CXX) $(CFLAGS) -c $< -o $@

%.d:%.c
    $(CXX) -MM -I. $< > $@

include $(DEPEND)

.PHONY:clean
clean:
    -rm -f $(EXEC) *.o *.d *~
```